# SQL Server Stored Procedure Multiple Insert in a single table from Array

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure to insert records into a table. And do this at least 12 times in a loop to insert multiple records which is very inefficient.

here is the procedure as CREATED

```
 Create PROC [dbo].[SP_INSERT_G_SAMPLING]
 @GameID INT,
 @ScoreID INT
 as 
 begin
 INSERT INTO GAMESCORE (GAMEID, SCOREID) VALUES
 (@GameID, @ScoreID)
 end
```

I pass on the values ex(1,3) and loop with more values from the website.

I want to however pass on all the values at one time like (1,3),(4,5),(8,9)

and then alter the above procedure to receive and insert multiple rows.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_INSERT_G_SAMPLING]
@totalinsert nvarchar(Max) 

INSERT INTO GAMESCORE (GAMEID, SCOREID) VALUES
(@totalinsert)
```

with    @totalinsert being like (1,3),(4,5),(8,9) pushed from the webpage.

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?  Table Value Parameters (TVP) are the preferred way of doing this.

Comment: Did you consider using of XML data type in SQL Server?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: SQL Server 2005 on the server. locally I have 12. I want to go with something that will work for 05 and up.

Answer (score 2):

What you're going to have to do is write a table valued function which accepts the multi-value string and breaks it out into a table object. If you can change your source to use a record delimiter instead of having comma sets it would be slightly easier to process. An example of that would look like this.

The below is pure psuedo and has not been validated in any way, just meant to give you a rough idea of where to go.

ex: @TotalInsert = 1,2|4,5|8,9

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
  (
     value1 INT,
     value2 INT
  )
DECLARE @setlist VARCHAR(max);

WHILE Len(@TotalInsert) > 0
  BEGIN
      SET @setlist = LEFT(@totalinsert, Charindex('|', @totalinsert))

      INSERT INTO @results
      SELECT LEFT(@setlist, Charindex(',', @setlist) - 1),
             RIGHT(@setlist, Charindex(',', Reverse(@setlist)) + 1)

      SET @totalinsert = RIGHT(@totalinsert, Len(@totalinsert) - Len(@setlist))
  END
```

Comment: Because this is meant to be a table valued function, when you are writing a function of that type you store the values into a table variable before returning them from the function. Examples can be found in msdn: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: David how do I get the function to execute the stored procedure and insert? I have played around with it for a while and all I get are errors. Having read tons of articles already on this and tried a lot them, I am now more confused than ever.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using .NET for your website since you're also using SQL Server.

Have a look at [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this page also includes a nice example of how to use the table valued parameters in .NET.

Check [here](http://sqlfool.com/2008/11/one-to-many-inserts-with-table-valued-parameters/) for a better example of making a stored procedure with a table valued parameter in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full discussion:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#XMLlist%20of%20values

Personally, I sent xml to the stored procedure, I "shred it" into @variable or #temp tables, then I do my INSERT/UPDATE/MERGE/DELETE from there.

Here is a fuller discussion on xml-shredding.

http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2007/06/shredding-xml-in-sql-server-2005.html

My personal trick is to create a strong dataset, populate the strong dataset with rows, and use the ds.GetXml() to send the xml down to the TSQL.  With a strong dataset, I get strong-typing when populating the values.  But at the end of the day, dataset is just some super fancy xml.